# Patterns in Lua with space

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

How could I use `string.gmatch(text, pattern)` to do this:

```
text = "Hello.%23 Awesome7^.."
pattern = --what to put here?
for word in string.gmatch(text, pattern) do
  print(word)
end
--Result
>test
Hello.%23
Awesome7^..
>
```

I have been using `"%w+%p"`, but this results in:

```
>test
Hello.
%
23
Awesome7^
.
.
```

Which is not the desired result.

Note:  I have not tested this exact string, it could vary... but still, does not create the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example, every word contains no spaces, and are separated by spaces, so the simplest pattern is `"%S+"`:

```
text = "Hello.%23 Awesome7^.."
pattern = "%S+"
for word in string.gmatch(text, pattern) do
  print(word)
end
```

`"%s"` matches a space character, `"%S"` matches a non-space character.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in gmatch printing  " "?
EDIT: nvm, I didn't know capital letters did different things

Comment: @KingofGamesYami Give it a test, note that it's capital `"%S+"`.